# jquery: Trying to make image into hyperlink

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, element, addition

I'm nearly where I want to be, except that I can't figure out how to turn var imgt into a hyperlinked image. I've tried some things, but it keeps returning [object][Object]

```
$j('#hp-featured-item > div[id^="post-"]').each(function() {
      var id=this.id.match(/post-(\d+)/);
      var imgt = $j("img:eq(0)");

      // I tried this but it didn't work
      // var imgt = $j("<a href='/blog/?p="+id[1]+"'>"+$j("img:eq(0)")+"</a>");

      var pt = $j("p:not(:has(img)):eq(0)");
      var hh = $j("h2:eq(0)");
      $j(this).html('');
      $j(this).append(imgt).append(hh).append(pt);
});
```

/// Updated code

```
$j('#hp-featured-item > div[id^="post-"]').each(function() {
                var id=this.id.match(/^post-([0-9]+)$/);
                var imgt = $j("img:eq(0)");
                $j(imgt).wrap($j('<a>').attr('href', '/'));
                var pt = $j("p:not(:has(img)):eq(0)");
                var hh = $j("h2:eq(0)");
                $j(this).html('');
                $j(this).append(imgt).append(hh).append(pt);
        });
```

Ok, I put it in the comment, but I'll put it here too based on your suggestion...  Essentially, the original html output varies greatly in structure.  Sometimes it's

```
<img /> 
<h2> </h2> 
<p> </p>
<p> <img /> </p>
<h2> </h2>
<p> </p>
```

Sometimes, it's just:

```
<h2> </h2>
<p><img /></p>
<p> text </p>
```

etc...

I want to pull the first `<img />`, the first `<h2>`, and the first `<p>` (that isn't wrapped around an image) and print them out in that order:

```
<img />
<h2>
<p>
```

And, the rest can just go away...  It's just a summary view...

Well, ok... I added this to the bottom, and it seems to work:

```
$j(this).each(function() {
                        var img = $j('img');
                        $j(img).wrap($j('<a>').attr('href', '/'));
                });
```

Comment: "print them out in that order" - the output html that you want doesnt have the anchor around the img. Should it?

Comment: when you say it returns "[object][Object]" .. how is that not what you want? after all, you *are* dealing with a jQuery object. If you alert any object it would give you [object][Object] since you're not doing low level DOM scripting.

Comment: "I've tried some things" - can you be more specific on how your code doesn't work? since any jQuery object when alerted is object Object, that part shouldn't matter at all.

It would be far easier if you took a whole snippet of HTML source in one of those divisions, posted the source ENTIRELY, showed the output of the source AFTER the JS did its work, and point out HOW it doesn't actually do what it's supposed to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [jQuery.prototype.wrap](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/wrap) for this:

```
$j('#hp-featured-item > div[id^="post-"]').each(function() {
      var id=this.id.match(/post-(\d+)/);
      var imgt = $j("img:eq(0)");

      $(imgt).wrap( 
          $('<a>').attr('href', '/blog/?p=' + id[1])
      );

});
```

This worked for me:

```
$('.post').each(function() {
    var img = $('img', this), src = $(img).attr('src')
    $(img).wrap( 
             $('<a>').attr('href', src)
    );
});
```

http://jsbin.com/iyabu

Make sure the href attribute you set it to is right.

Comment: This isn't working for me... I tried different variations, including what you have above... 

I tried:
<pre>
$j(imgt).wrap( 
    $j('<a>').attr('href', '/blog/?p=' + id[1])
);
</pre>
and 

<pre>imgt.wrap('<a href="/blog/?p=' + id[1] + '"></a>');</pre>

But neither had any effect...

Comment: I updated my example. Stop making it complex if you can't get it and try simplifying it as much as possible, it might be that your array doesn't contain 2 elements, use a static href value to test.

Comment: small point of note: I'd use `/^post-([0-9]+)$/` for your regex so it doesn't match "blahpost-123blah"

Comment: By the way, you *are* getting rid of your manual .html() and .append stuff? Can you please provide the updatd code.

Comment: Tried the second example, and it's still just returning the <img> html with no wrapper.  The html that's originally produced has many <img>, but I'm only interested in the first one it finds, thus the 
var imgt = $j("img:eq(0)");

I tried:
$j(img).wrap( $j('<a>').attr('href', '/') ); 

and 

var imgt = $j("img:eq(0)").wrap( $j('<a>').attr('href', '/') );

But, it's just returning <img ... />  

I'm using the jquery noconflict thing, which is why I've got the $j in there...

Comment: Yes, I'm emptying the html because there's a bunch of additional stuff that I don't want to display...

Comment: Then that's the problem, .wrap wraps it IMMEDIATELY, I suggest you use .wrap and get rid of stuff with .remove or .hide but if you're going to .append you will need to do it correctly and it's harder, that and you haven't shown any HTML source so we can't easily see what you want to append in what order..

Comment: You should probably update your entire original description with what you *really* want to do.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by not showing any HTML source.  In its original form, it may look like this: 
<div id="hp-featured-item"><div id="post-6"><h2>Some title</h2><p>Some paragraph</p><img src="/someimage.jpg" /><p>another paragraph</p><p><img src="/anotherimage.jpg" /></p><blockquote>some stuff</blockquote>  etc., etc.  It varies...  But, what I'm trying to do is pull the *first* <img>, the *first* <h2>, and the *first* <p> and place them in that order.  <img> <h2> <p>  so that it looks like this:

<img ... />
<h2> title </h2>
<p> paragraph </p>

And just dump the rest...

Comment: Can you edit your *original* post with the full source please, so it's easier to read?

Comment: Yes... I posted the comment before I saw your last comment... sorry!